# How can I fill in the gap in this model without this tessellation/deformation occurring?

Tags: 3d-models, tinkercad

To start off my apologies if this question seems somewhat unclear. For context I am attaching the images of the model and the modified version in TinkerCAD. My issue is that I cannot fill in the gap on in the left arm of the gripper without these deformations happening.

[image]
[image]
[image]

What I would like to do is to fill in the gap and then make a hole that fits the servo motor head. At the moment the printed model loosely fits on top of the servo motor and when screwed in place does not have the range of motion I need.

I would be extremely grateful for any suggestions on how to fill in the gap without the problem occurring in TinkerCAD. I know I may not have tried the most sophisticated solution by just filling in the gap with another shape but I could not modify the model in any other way.

Comment: Imgur link seems broken.  However, welcome to 3D Printing Stack Exchange.  This seems like a good first question, though I'm not certain 3D CAD software is on topic here.  You should take the [tour] and read through the [FAQ] to better understand how our site works.

Comment: Please always embed images instead of linking to external content, SE has their own imgur that retains the image as long as SE exists. I've updated the question for you. Embedding graphics will cause graphics and question to be together, saving the readers time so they can put more time in answering.

Comment: "Embedding graphics will cause graphics and question to be together, saving the readers time so they can put more time in answering."  Not to mention preventing the question from showing a dead link if/when the hosting site deletes the image, goes down, etc.  Likely not a problem with Imgur as such, but still a potential issue.